# c# SqlDecimal flipping sign in multiplication of small numbers

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

It seems I'm running into [more woes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116994/sqldecimal-issues-in-sqlclr-project) with 'my most favorite datatype' SqlDecimal.
I'm wondering if this should be considered a bug or not.

When I multiply two small numbers in SQL I get the expected result. When I run the same numbers through a SQLCLR function the results are, well surprising.

c# code:

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

namespace TestMultiplySQLDecimal
{
    public static class Multiplier
    {
        [SqlFunction(DataAccess=DataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true,IsPrecise = true)]
        public static SqlDecimal Multiply(SqlDecimal a, SqlDecimal b)
        {
            if (a.IsNull || b.IsNull) return SqlDecimal.Null;
            return a*b;
        }
    }
}
```

SQL Code:

```
USE tempdb
GO
IF DB_ID('test') IS NOT NULL DROP DATABASE test
GO
CREATE DATABASE test
GO
USE test
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY TestMultiplySQLDecimal 
FROM 'C:\Users\tralalalaa\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\TestMultiplySQLDecimal\TestMultiplySQLDecimal\bin\Release\TestMultiplySQLDecimal.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_multiply(@a decimal(38,8), @b decimal(18,8)) 
RETURNS decimal(38,8)
EXTERNAL NAME TestMultiplySQLDecimal.[TestMultiplySQLDecimal.Multiplier].Multiply
GO
DECLARE @a decimal(38, 8),
        @b decimal(18, 8),
        @c decimal(38, 8),
        @f decimal(38, 8)

SELECT @a = -0.00000450,
       @b = 0.193,
       @c = NULL,
       @f = NULL

SELECT @c = @a * @b,
       @f = dbo.fn_multiply(@a, @b)

SELECT multiply = null, c = @c, f = @f
```

The outcome of this is : 
c = -0.00000100
f = +0.00000100

I know the 'absolute' difference is 'minimal' and I've "played down" bigger errors blaming it on "rounding differences"... But it's going to be hard to explain to clients that negative times positive results in positive.
And after all, T-SQL supports it fine...

I can try to work around it by using decimal(28,8) instead of decimal(38,8) but I'll run into other (totally unrelated) issues then =/

---

The following console application exhibits the same problem, without having to get SQL Server/SQLCLR involved:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace PlayAreaCSCon
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dec1 = new SqlDecimal(-0.00000450d);
            var dec2 = new SqlDecimal(0.193d);
            dec1 = SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(dec1, 38, 8);
            dec2 = SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(dec2, 18, 8);
            Console.WriteLine(dec1 * dec2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Prints `0.000001`

Comment: Try converting it to the native dotnet decimal, performing the calculation, then converting back: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx

Comment: Yes, of course this is a bug. All rounding and magnitude issues aside, multiplying a negative number by a positive number should never yield a positive number, that's bizarro math. Per @Damien, this appears to be a bug where the code checks if the result is zero (and wrongly concludes that it is); the intent in the code is clearly to end up with the correct sign for non-zero results irrespective of the precision/scale of the arguments.

Comment: Assuming the bug is limited in scope to the sign (which it appears to be), the simple workaround (ugly as it is) is to adjust it yourself afterwards: `result = dec1 * dec2; if (dec1.IsPositive != dec2.IsPositive && result.IsPositive) result = -result;` Don't forget a comment to explain why you're doing that.

Comment: @Ben Converting to .net Decimal and then back indeed would solve the issue, but then my range goes down from 38 digits to 28. Not saying that is a disaster, it simply 'shouldn't be necessary' IMHO.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've been considering 'correcting the sign' but I wasn't sure if the sign was the only thing affected. Going by Damien_The_Unbeliever 's answer this (luckily?) seems to be the case.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the edit, I had tried to create the SqlDecimal in c#, but the constructor where you can specify the required scale and precision left me flabbergasted.

Comment: There's little guarantee that there aren't more obscure bugs lurking in there, given the paucity of the test set, but *this particular one* should be fixable that way. Of course, if you want a more thorough approach you could consider reimplementing it yourself... I mean, if you're really, really bored. :-)

Comment: This bug in the BCL can also be seen from PowerShell, of course. Just paste this line: `[System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal]::ConvertToPrecScale(-0.00000450,38,8) * [System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal]::ConvertToPrecScale(0.193,18,8)`

Comment: I've accepted Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer as he figured out where this comes from. That said, as a workaround for now I'll use srutzky's suggestion to lower the precision of the input parameters to 28,8 and 15,8 respectively. This gives me a 38,10 in return which is then stored back again into a 28,8 in the database. This might cause an overflow, but it was like that in the past too, so that's no issue. It will however be more precise which is a nice 'extra' next to solving this issue we ran into. Thanks all!

Comment: PS: as a quick search on MS website didn't show anyone already reported this bug I've done it myself here : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3120261

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the bug is located around about line [1550 of `SqlDecimal`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SQLTypes/SQLDecimal.cs,1550):

```
ret = new SqlDecimal(rgulRes, (byte)culRes, (byte)ResPrec, 
                     (byte)ActualScale, fResPositive);

if (ret.FZero ())
     ret.SetPositive();

ret.AssertValid();

ret.AdjustScale(lScaleAdjust, true);

return ret;
```

It first constructs a new decimal using the final scale parameter. It next checks whether the result is "zero", based on the passed in constructor parameters.

Then, after asserting everything is valid, it performs a scale adjustment.

At the time that the FZero check is performed, the result is something like `-0.0000008685`. And we know that the *final* scale will be 6 because we're at the limits on resulting [scale and precision](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190476.aspx). Well, the first 6 digits are all zero.

It's only after that, when the scale is being adjusted, that it takes rounding into consideration and moves a `1` into the final decimal position.

It's a bug. Unfortunately, the source code for the SQL Server native implementation of `decimal` isn't publicly available, so we cannot compare it to the managed implementation of `SqlDecimal` to see how similar they are and how the original avoids the same bug.

Comment: It appears this bug was [copied over](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c5c75db7c00047d603522fd6e21f350099e09bbb/src/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/SQLTypes/SQLDecimal.cs) to CoreFX. A new [test](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c5c75db7c00047d603522fd6e21f350099e09bbb/src/System.Data.Common/tests/System/Data/SqlTypes/SqlDecimalTest.cs) might be in order. (They're not what you'd call exhaustive.) Yay for open source.

Comment: I'm honestly impressed =)

Answer (score 2):

While the difference in behavior between the T-SQL and .NET implementations is "troubling" and does point to a bug, and while @Damien_The_Unbeliever's [fine investigative work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41939483/577765) might very well identify the cause of this behavior (hard to verify at the moment as there is a lot of code in the `SqlDecimal` implementation and some of it uses imprecise calculations using `double` to get around .NET not supporting more than 28 digits), there is quite possibly a larger issue being ignored here: both answers (i.e. `c = -0.00000100   f = +0.00000100` ) are wrong! Perhaps we should not be so hasty to determine the winner between "The sky is plaid" and "The sky is polka-dotted" ;-)

This is a case where we probably need to be a bit more pragmatic in the goal, more understanding of the limitations of Decimal operations, and widen our scope of testing.

To begin with, while it might seem like a good idea to reserve the maximum datatype space for an unknown set of inputs, using `DECIMAL(38, y)` is similar to using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for all strings. Yes, it can usually fit anything you throw at it, but there are consequences. And there is an additional consequence in Decimal operations given the nature of how the resulting precision and scale are calculated, *especially* when giving so little room to the "scale" (i.e. the 8 digits) and yet multiplying very small numbers. Meaning: if you aren't going to be using the full range of 30 digits to the left of the decimal (i.e. `DECIMAL(38, 8)` ) then don't specify `DECIMAL(38, 8)`. For the input parameters, just specify the max size allowed for each of those values. Given that both are below 0, using something like `DECIMAL(20, 18)` (or even `DECIMAL(18, 8)` ) would not only be quite flexible, but would produce the correct result. OR, if you really do need to allow for large values, then give more space to the digits to the right of the decimal (i.e. the "scale") by specifying something like `DECIMAL(38, 28)` which gives 10 digits to the left of the decimal, and 28 to the right of it.

**Original DECIMAL(38, 8) for everything**

```sql
DECLARE @a DECIMAL(38, 8),
        @b DECIMAL(38, 8),
        @c DECIMAL(38, 8);

SELECT @a = -0.00000450,
       @b = 0.193;

SELECT @c = @a * @b;

SELECT @a * @b AS [RawCalculation], @c AS [c];
```

Returns:

```
RawCalculation    c
-0.000001         -0.00000100
```

**Using DECIMAL(18, 8)**

```sql
DECLARE @a DECIMAL(18, 8),
        @b DECIMAL(18, 8),
        @c DECIMAL(38, 18),
        @d DECIMAL(20, 18),
        @e DECIMAL(38, 8);

SELECT @a = -0.00000450,
       @b = 0.193;

SELECT @c = @a * @b,
       @d = @a * @b,
       @e = @a * @b;

SELECT @a * @b AS [RawCalculation], @c AS [c], @d AS [d], @e AS [e];
```

Returns:

```
RawCalculation          c                         d                         e
-0.0000008685000000     -0.000000868500000000     -0.000000868500000000     -0.00000087
```

**Using DECIMAL(38, 28)**

```sql
DECLARE @a DECIMAL(38, 28),
        @b DECIMAL(38, 28),
        @c DECIMAL(38, 18),
        @d DECIMAL(20, 18),
        @e DECIMAL(38, 8);

SELECT @a = -0.00000450,
       @b = 0.193;

SELECT @c = @a * @b,
       @d = @a * @b,
       @e = @a * @b;

SELECT @a * @b AS [RawCalculation], @c AS [c], @d AS [d], @e AS [e];
```

Returns:

```
RawCalculation          c                         d                            e
-0.00000086850000000    -0.000000868500000000     -0.000000868500000000        -0.00000087
```

**.NET sample code**

The following code is based on the sample code that @Damien added to the question. I expanded it to do additional tests to show how the variations of precision and scale affect the calculation, and to output the various properties at each step. Please note that the literal representation of a decimal in .NET uses `M` or `m`, not `d` (though it did not make a difference in this test): [decimal (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

namespace SqlDecimalMultiplication
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void DisplayStuffs(SqlDecimal Dec1, SqlDecimal Dec2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1 ~ {0}", Dec1.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("1 ~ Precision: {0}; Scale: {1}; IsPositive: {2}", Dec1.Precision, Dec1.Scale, Dec1.IsPositive);
            Console.WriteLine("2 ~ {0}", Dec2.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("2 ~ Precision: {0}; Scale: {1}; IsPositive: {2}", Dec2.Precision, Dec2.Scale, Dec2.IsPositive);

            Console.Write("\nRESULT:    ");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine(Dec1 * Dec2);
            Console.ResetColor();

            return;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dec1 = new SqlDecimal(-0.00000450m);
            var dec2 = new SqlDecimal(0.193m);

            Console.WriteLine("=======================\n\nINITIAL:");
            DisplayStuffs(dec1, dec2);


            dec1 = SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(dec1, 38, 8);
            dec2 = SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(dec2, 18, 8);

            Console.WriteLine("=======================\n\nAFTER (38, 8) & (18, 8):");
            DisplayStuffs(dec1, dec2);


            dec1 = SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(dec1, 18, 8);

            Console.WriteLine("=======================\n\nAFTER (18, 8) & (18, 8):");
            DisplayStuffs(dec1, dec2);


            dec1 = SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(dec1, 38, 28);
            dec2 = SqlDecimal.ConvertToPrecScale(dec2, 38, 28);

            Console.WriteLine("=======================\n\nAFTER (38, 28) & (38, 28):");
            DisplayStuffs(dec1, dec2);

            Console.WriteLine("=======================");
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
=======================

INITIAL:
1 ~ -0.00000450
1 ~ Precision: 8; Scale: 8; IsPositive: False
2 ~ 0.193
2 ~ Precision: 3; Scale: 3; IsPositive: True

RESULT:    -0.00000086850
=======================

AFTER (38, 8) & (18, 8):
1 ~ -0.00000450
1 ~ Precision: 38; Scale: 8; IsPositive: False
2 ~ 0.19300000
2 ~ Precision: 18; Scale: 8; IsPositive: True

RESULT:    0.000001
=======================

AFTER (18, 8) & (18, 8):
1 ~ -0.00000450
1 ~ Precision: 18; Scale: 8; IsPositive: False
2 ~ 0.19300000
2 ~ Precision: 18; Scale: 8; IsPositive: True

RESULT:    -0.0000008685000000
=======================

AFTER (38, 28) & (38, 28):
1 ~ -0.0000045000000000000000000000
1 ~ Precision: 38; Scale: 28; IsPositive: False
2 ~ 0.1930000000000000000000000000
2 ~ Precision: 38; Scale: 28; IsPositive: True

RESULT:    -0.00000086850000000
=======================
```

### CONCLUSION

While there probably is a bug in `SqlDecimal`, you should likely not be encountering it if specifying the Precision and Scale of the *input parameters* "properly". Unless, of course, you truly do have need for 38 digits on incoming values, but most use cases would never need that.

ALSO, the reason for highlighting "*input parameters*" in the paragraph directly above is to indicate that the *return value* should naturally be a larger precision (and scale) so as to accommodate the increase in precision and/or scale as a result of certain operations. So there is nothing wrong with keeping `DECIMAL(38, 28)` or `DECIMAL(38,18)` as the datatype of the return value.

---

**Related Note:**

For SQLCLR UDFs (i.e. scalar functions), do not use this pattern IF it covers *all* input parameters:

```cs
if (a.IsNull || b.IsNull) return SqlDecimal.Null;
```

IF the idea is to return a `NULL` if *any* of the input params is `NULL`, then you should use the following option in the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement:

```
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
```

as that will avoid calling the .NET code entirely!

Comment: I wouldn't describe the SQL result as wrong. It's only the assignment to a `decimal(38,8)` which re-extends the scale and adds extra `0`s to the right of the already rounded result.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just updated with more complete T-SQL examples. Unless I am doing something wrong, the assignment to `DECIMAL(38, 8)` isn't the culprit; it is the usage of `DECIMAL(38, 8)` in the first place for both operands, as per the MSDN chart that you linked to.

Comment: The point is, if you perform any calculation that (due to those rules) produces a `decimal(x,6)` result, and you *then* assign that result to a `decimal(x,20)` variable/column, you won't suddenly obtain extra digits. You'll get whatever the result was, rounded to 6 decimal places, and then re-expanded to more decimal places. The result of the multiplication in the OPs post was `-0.000001`. Which is correct to 6 d.p. It was only when it was assigned to a variable of a different type that the extra zeroes appeared.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Of course, but you are missing my point, which isn't about "extra" zeroes. Simply put, `-0.000001` (i.e. 6 decimal places) _is_ wrong given the reality in which these operations are being done. Only if the O.P. _truly_ needs 30 significant digits could `-0.000001` be considered correct in any practical sense. On a technical level there is a problem, but it's a problem that the O.P. most likely doesn't need to encounter, hence not find a work-around to.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. By 'experimentation' we had come to a similar conclusion regarding the effect of working with 'overly big' datatypes. The problem is that the SQLCLR function _could_ be used to work on 38,8 numerics some day, even though we don't expect it to _right now_. I can leave out the SqlFacet stuff and have the c# code work with 'any' scale/precision; but the SQL definition of the function requires me to 'hardcode' the parameters anyway =/ I think I'll experiment a bit with 'shifting' the scale/precision according to the actual number and then do the multiplication.

Comment: @deroby Yer welcome. And the `SqlFacet()` info, with regards to "precision" and "scale" (among others) is only used by SSDT to know how to generate the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement. But whatever the CREATE FUNCTION statement shows as the datatypes is what will be used, regardless of what, if anything, is specified via `SqlFacet`. BUT, again, _why_ do you need a scale of 38 on incoming values? Also, you can have multiple T-SQL wrapper objects referencing the same CLR object. That same method can have multiple `CREATE FUNCTION` statements using it, each with different scale + precision values.

Comment: @deroby P.S. please see the update I just added to the end of my answer, under **Related Note**.

Comment: The reason we had 38 on incoming values was probably that 'bigger is better'. For now I'm figuring out if we have any clients that actually need more than the 25,8 (!) we use in the UDDT that we ship by default. Given the fact that a lot of GUI stuff is written in c# and (implicitly) converts the incoming SQL values into decimals (e.g. via EF) I'm pretty sure we never go above 28. // PS: The `WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` would have worked here indeed; I must admit I've never really used (and pretty much forgot about) it because functionally we often use NULL as a placeholder for 'default'.

Comment: @deroby Yeah, it is an all-too-common misconception that one should use the largest possible `DECIMAL` container when in fact that does more harm than good, especially given the relatively few use cases for storing so many digits. I have been meaning to blog about this very topic and is has tripped up others on other forums / threads. If there is any place in the code where the values are handled as .NET `decimal` types, then you are never using more than 28 digits, hence, no need to have input params above 28 for the precision. I still wonder why such a low scale, seems that should go up.

Comment: I'm guessing 8 numbers behind the decimal suffices for what is mostly financial data. For now I'm going to 'fix' the issue by putting the relevant SqlFacets to 28,8. I've got one table in the database where we specifically store 38,7 numbers, but I'm guessing those are not "related" to this SQLCLR project. Will need some digging but I'm glad to be on the right track again.

Comment: @deroby If these numbers are for financial purposes, you should be specifying `DECIMAL(19, 4)`, which is the same precision and scale (effectively) used by `MONEY` / `SqlMoney`. Remember, you only need to be concerned with base values used in calculations, not the potential return values. When Decimal / Numeric operands are properly sized, the resulting precision and scale increase to fit the largest possible values given the operands. Since noone can have a fractional penny, and nobody has more than $99 trillion, anything over `(16, 2)` is useless. But `(19, 4)` is fine as it matches `MONEY`.

Comment: @deroby However, if this function (and hence its parameters) are for interim calculations of financial data, such as interest / mortgages, etc, then I would give more space to the scale value, such as `(28, 14)` or something like that. With only `8` for the scale you will get a lot of truncation and rounding, in which case you might as well use the easier, and more efficient / performant `FLOAT` / `SqlDouble` / `Double` :-).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134610/discussion-between-deroby-and-srutzky).